# hibernate template find() HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException

Tags: spring, hibernate

We have some legacy code that works in one environment and not another.  The offending block is:

```
String hql =  "from UsrOrgLvlAsgnT where usrAccountT.usrId = ? ";
List<UsrOrgLvlAsgnT> result= getHibernateTemplate().find(hql,usrId);
return result;
```

the log seems to indicate two SQL calls being run, getting the main record (UsrOrgLvlAsgnT) runs first and I presume succeeds, but then a second call to get a detail record runs, and seems to issue the error.

Problem 1 - This should not be eager fetching.  HBM follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.UsrOrgLvlAsgnT" table="USR_ORG_LVL_ASGN_T" schema="UMC" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="usrAsgnId" type="int">
            <column name="USR_ASGN_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="usrAccountT" class="gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.UsrAccountT" fetch="select" cascade="save-update">
            <column name="USR_ID" length="60" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="structureL" class="gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.StructureL" update="true" insert="true" fetch="select" cascade="save-update">
            <column name="STRUCTURE_CD" length="2" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="orgLvl1L" class="gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl1L" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select" not-found="ignore" not-null="false" cascade="save-update">
            <column name="STRUCTURE_CD" length="2" not-null="true" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL1_CD" length="5" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="orgLvl2L" class="gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2L" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select" not-found="ignore" not-null="false" cascade="save-update">
            <column name="STRUCTURE_CD" length="2" not-null="true" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL1_CD" length="5" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL2_CD" length="6" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="orgLvl3L" class="gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl3L" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select" not-found="ignore" not-null="false" cascade="save-update">
            <column name="STRUCTURE_CD" length="2" not-null="true" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL1_CD" length="5" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL2_CD" length="6" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL3_CD" length="12" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="orgLvl4L" class="gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl4L" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select" not-found="ignore" not-null="false" cascade="save-update">
            <column name="STRUCTURE_CD" length="2" not-null="true" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL1_CD" length="5" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL2_CD" length="6" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL3_CD" length="12" />
            <column name="ORG_LVL4_CD" length="6" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="updtTmstmp" type="timestamp" generated="always">
            <column name="UPDT_TMSTMP" length="26" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dfltOrgLvl" type="java.lang.Character">
            <column name="DFLT_ORG_LVL" length="1" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Problem 2 - This FK relationship is a legacy deal and the folks before us used blanks for nulls.  I have no idea why.  But I can't realistically change it at this time.  Is there a way to make hibernate handle this empty relationship without blowing up?

The Exception:

```
[10/15/13 10:17:12:897 EDT] 0000002e SystemOut     O ERROR [WebContainer : 7] (St60Servlet.java:82) - Error in St60. Process will not continue: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: No row with the given identifier exists: [gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2L#gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2LId@3d4ed6f3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2L#gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2LId@3d4ed6f3]
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.services.St60Service.fetchOU(St60Service.java:373)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.services.St60Service.buildOU(St60Service.java:325)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.services.St60Service.verifyUserGroups(St60Service.java:178)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.services.St60Service.verifyUpdate(St60Service.java:64)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.services.St60Service$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7efbe043.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.services.St60Service$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$d08c239.verifyUpdate(<generated>)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.St60.St60Servlet.doGet(St60Servlet.java:73)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1536)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1470)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.utils.hibernate.DBParameterFilter.doFilter(DBParameterFilter.java:46)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:363)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:858)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:824)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3742)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: No row with the given identifier exists: [gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2L#gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2LId@3d4ed6f3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2L#gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2LId@3d4ed6f3]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:663)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:912)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:908)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.dao.HibernateAccountInfoDaoImpl.fetchUsrOrgLvlAsgnById(HibernateAccountInfoDaoImpl.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor914.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
    at $Proxy70.fetchUsrOrgLvlAsgnById(Unknown Source)
    at gov.usdoj.afms.umc.services.St60Service.fetchOU(St60Service.java:360)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: 
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2L#gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.OrgLvl2LId@3d4ed6f3]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$2.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.returnNarrowedProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:320)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1028)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:623)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:773)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: I wish I could try this my self, I would add left joins so it would not try to pull the values from a many-one relationship which fails.

"from UsrOrgLvlAsgnT a left outer join a.orgLvl2L b where usrAccountT.usrId = ?"

Comment: Also, can you change the fetch type to 'join' and see?

Comment: Please post what `usrId` is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The usrId is a user ID that was pulled from an LDAP store.  It would be meaningless to you, but it is a valid user ID and is in the parent table, but not the child (org 2) because that FK is empty.

Comment: @Zeus - I tried to make it fetch type join.  Same problem.  I tried putting the left join that you suggested in your first post in, and that caused " java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with gov.usdoj.afms.umc.hibernate.model.UsrOrgLvlAsgnT", I guess because it changes the response object type.  All the legacy code works against that object, so I can't really change the object.